# Merging and obfuscating same jar file?

Tags: java, netbeans, merge, obfuscation, proguard

I want to merge my .jar application with my libraries, on the other hand I want to obfuscate my code. I tried to use ProGuard with zOneJar but Proguard isn't able to obfuscate a merged jar. How can I accomplish this?

I am using Netbeans on Windows 7 64bit.

I am looking forward to your suggestions! :)

Comment: What exactly happens when you use proguard on the merged jar ??, is there an error message ??. Progaurd has class filters which can limit what proguard checks. See the manual for details  http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! :) I tried to keep classes with the keep parameter and as a classname I chose com.** and sun.** and so on to skip all the libraries included in my .jar. But it still doesn't work. Here is a part of the output: http://pastebin.com/ZvWHwDry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still using zOneJar but I switched to JShrink. JShrink is working like a charm, and I am very happy to be able to merge and obfuscate my code now.

http://www.e-t.com/jshrink.html

No additional settings - just obfuscate the merged jar.

Greetings,
Dominik